# Big Oh and Big Omega when $n$ and $\log n$ terms are in $f(n)$

Tags: asymptotics

having problems with big oh and big omega functions when there is a $\log n$ added or subtracted. For example how do I deal with $n+\log n$ or $n-\log n$ when I have to determine whether the function is in $\Omega(n)$ or in $\Omega(n^2)$? For example, is $n-\log n$ in $\Omega(n)$ or in $\Omega(n^2)$?

I cannot ignore the log function and am not sure how to deal with it.  Polynomials and logs when multiplied I find OK. But I have a mental block over this one so help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You are right that you cannot *a priori* ignore additional terms, although morally you can as the "smaller" terms do not contribute to the asymptotic growth.

As an example $f(n) :=n+\log n$ is in $\Theta(n)$. Why? Going back to the definition, we want to show that $f(n)$ is in $O(n)$ and in $\Omega(n)$. Showing $f(n)\in \Omega(n)$ is immediate, as $f(n) \geq n$ for all $n>0$.

To show that $f(n)$ is in $O(n)$, simply notice that for large enough $n$ (say $n>N$ for some constant $N$) we have $\log n \leq n$ and thus $f(n)\leq 2n$ for all $n>N$. By definition $f(n)\in O(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you CAN ignore the log function in a sum or substraction, because the log is always asymptotically negligible in front of $n^x$, for every $x > 0$.

If you consider the function $f(n) = n^x + \alpha\log n$ (where $x > 0$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$), then there exists $A, B \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$ such that $An^x \leq f(n) \leq Bn^x$. That means that $f\in \Omega(n^x)$ and $f\in \mathcal{O}(n^x)$.

Comment: Agreed with the f(n) =n^2 or cubed -logn as the polynomial grows faster we can ignore the log n. f(n) grows faster than log n. Is it sufficient then to just prove that f(n) =n and is in Big omega  and ignore the log term on the basis that as Tassle says logn<n . is this sufficient for a formal proof

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really get your question… I'll try to answer what I understood. When you have a sum $f(n) = g(n) + h(n)$ with $h \in o(g)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation), then $f\in \Omega(g)$ and $f\in \mathcal{O}(g)$. This is the case in your question, since $\log \in o(n^x)$ for $x > 0$, and yes it is sufficient for a proof.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, $n-\log(n)=\theta(n)$, that is $n-\log(n) = \Omega(n)$ and also $n-\log(n)=O(n)$.

You can see this like that:

- $n-\log(n)\le n = O(n)$
- $n-\log(n) \ge n - 0.5n = \Omega(n)$

Comment: as n-logn is always less than n the function can only be in Big Oh . It cannot be in Big omega as if I divide by n^2 to fiind c I get 1-logn > or equal to c. As n gets greater than 2 n-logn gets more negative and c is no longer a constant so it cannot be in Big Omega.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: From a certain point $log(n)\le0.5n$. This means that $n-\log(n)$ will actually not be negative, but actually if you substitute the inequality you get $n-\log(n)\ge 0.5n$, which is $\Omega(n)$. However, you are correct that it is not $\Omega(n^2)$.

Comment: sorry. I meant n-logn is not in Big Omega (n) not Big Omega (n^2). My original question is to prove (n-logn) = Ω(n) true or false.  I was trying to prove it false by contradiction. Hence my reasoning of c needing to be a positive constant for all n> no.I am not sure where you came up with the 0.5n either. I plotted the graphs and n-logn is always under f(n)= n when n>1

Comment: As my answer showed, it is indeed always lower than $n$. But, in the same time, it is bigger than $0.5n$. Try to draw this graph as well

Comment: You are right and thank you for your help . In fact from what you have said I can prove that n-logn =big theta(n) .

Comment: Also, n-logn>= to 0.5n for n>= 4.